# sequence diagram

Tags: uml, software-design, sequence-diagram

I am browsing the code of a large open source application and would like to learn how it is designed and how it works. Is there a tool that can reverse engineer the C and C++ code into sequence diagrams?

May be this could be a bit far fetched but what about a tool which can give me the list of functions called (in various modules and in right order) when say the application is processing an input? Or help me quickly analyze a given application (esp one with a large code base)?

Looking forward to the answers as I am thinking this must be a well covered topic.

Comment: I have tried a lot of tools before giving up and created http://www.zenuml.com . I found reverse engineering code into sequence diagram is not really a good idea. I know a few tools do that well but still, the result is not quite readable. With ZenUML, you think loudly and visibly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some but they are expensive.  Rational Rose was the most well known before it got bought by IBM.

The nature of the C++ language makes it really hard to do static analysis. That is why there are so few tools that can do it.  Since the surge in non-C++ development using languages that support reflection/introspection, this type of tooling has really left C++ behind.  That isn't to say that are none, just they are harder to find and usually part of an expensive 4GL-like package.  Rational Rose was mainly a tool that let you diagram a system and it would help track the components and eventually produce source code in a variety of languages.  It could also reverse engineer source code into diagrams to a degree.

The Rational Rose product was pretty much superceded by Rational Requisite Pro, with a large portion of the functionality (focussed on Java) being folded into IBM's WebSphere Application Development platform, now referred to as RAD I believe.

The Rational tools were well known for being so comprehensive that they were really targeted for large development shops working with an equally large staff, usually starting at 50+ developers, for a single project.

Due to the complexity of the C++ language (from a tooling perspective), and the popularity of languages like Java and C#, vendors have really de-emphasized C++.

I'm not as knowledgeable about Visual Studio, which still supports C++, but I would be willing to guess that C++ UML support is only in the expensive professional editions like Pro or Ultimate.

Comment: Can I know more about these tools? I thought the topic must be well covered but now I am starting to think otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Asked before [C++ to UML ( Reverse engineer / Round-trip engineering )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407948/c-to-uml-reverse-engineer-round-trip-engineering).  Oddly enough Altova does not.  Seems to do most everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Sparx Systems' [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/index.html) can record the execution of an application and generate sequence diagrams from this trace, in addition to regular static reverse-engineering from source code. The Execution Analyzer supports (in EA 9.2):

- Microsoft Windows Native C
- Microsoft Windows Native C++
- Microsoft Windows Visual Basic
- Microsoft .NET Family (C#, J#, VB)
- Sun Microsystems Java
- PHP

You need at least the Professional edition of EA, which at the time of writing costs US$199 (one nine nine) for a single-seat license.

There's a [very old demo video](http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/demos/debuggingcs/debuggingcs.htm) available on the site (from three major versions ago).